# PHP Calculate Long Integer Range of Subnet ip2long

Tags: php, ip, ip2long

I am trying to determine whether a website visitor came from an EU country, and if so show them a cookie consent banner per their law.

I downloaded a table listing IPv4 of all EU countries (ie: 1.178.224.0/19) and uploaded it to mySQL.  There are 107,000 rows in the table. I can get the users IP using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].  I'm looking for the most simplified and quickest approach to check using PHP if the user's ip address falls in the range.

One idea was to create 2 columns in a table with the starting and ending long integers of each IPv4.  The website would change the users IP address to a long integer using ip2long() and then see if it falls within the range of the 2 columns of any IPv4.  Not sure if this is possible.  If that's a good idea, how do I get the starting and ending long integer of an IPv4 address?

I found several solutions to see if an IP falls within the range (ie: 1.178.224.0/19) listed in my table, but with 107,000 rows this would probably take a while to process.  I'm looking for a solution that runs quick so not to slow down every user who's not in an EU country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to implement geolocation yourself, you could use a free online service for that. You can implement this quite quickly. Take for instance this service:

http://geolocation-db.com/documentation

I would use Javascript not PHP, and only when an user is in an EU country you pop up the cookie consent banner.

Comment: Awesome, thank you KIKO!